# What is the jQuery syntax for saying "any element"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to hide a div named "div7" :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#div7").mouseover(function(){
       $(this).hide(2000);
   });
});
```

It works fine but I want to use it on any `div` or `element` in the `.html` file

What is the jQuery syntax for saying "any element" ?!

**Update**

All the answers gave the same result... I think it's my mistake for not being specific

What I want is if the mouse is over ("#what_ever"), then that "what ever" will get selected... not all divs or all elements in the body

Comment: Does "any" mean "any random" or "literally any" like first?

Comment: "literally any" i think

Comment: Keep in mind that when you "hide" an element, you also hide all of its children. So when you hide "body" on mouseover, everything in the document has been hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the elements of a given type, for example: all the divs, then you just have to specify the element name in the selector. If you want to select all the elements on a page then use `$( "*" )`

**In your case I have used $("body *") which means all the elements inside the body tag. Otherwise body tag would also be hidden on mouse-over.**

This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body *").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).hide(2000);
});
});
```

```css
div
{
background-color: #eee;  
  padding : 20px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> This is Div 1 </div>
  
  <div> This is Div 2 </div>
    
    <div> This is Div 3 </div>
      
      <div> This is Div 3 </div>
<p>This is paragraph</p>
<a> This is a Link</a>
```

Comment: i only want to hide only the one the mouse is over it

Comment: It only hides the selected div. I have inserted a code snippet. Please check.

Comment: nice work (Y).....it's my mistake for not beeing specific

what i want is if the mouse is over ("#what_ever") that what ever will get selected... not only divs

Comment: Updated the answer and code snippt for all elements

Answer (score 3):

Simply the `*` asterisk symbol means `any object`. This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).hide(2000);
    });
});
```

However, it looks like you're willing to hide all `divs` instead of `any object`.

**So you should be using:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).hide(2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: i only want to hide only the one the mouse is over it

Comment: @IbrahimHero That's what it does. Basically my code says: On mouseover a div, hide the div you're hovering your mouse over.

Comment: my bad ..i had the other divs in one big dive..sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to apply it to all divs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).hide(2000);
});
});
```

Here you provided "div" as a selector , you can provide div with class or something else also [See](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fcategory%2Fselectors%2F&ei=0VOFVKu9N8uAU_yXguAP&usg=AFQjCNFP7N8UvHOYUWpwOT49rwZKDbzHFA) Selectors refrence here

Comment: it works fine for the "all divs" but i want to select only the one the mouse is over it

Answer (score 1):

Use the asterisk symbol like this:

```
$('body *').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).hide(2000);
});
```